# Firefox extensions in Prism

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, mozilla-prism

I've read some posts around the web on making Firefox extensions work in Prism, but I haven't been able to get any running correctly.

Does anyone have a tutorial on this they could recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Prism/Extensions
It appears they have to be ported first